# Google Sign-In, Server-Side Access - why is it a less secure sign-in technology?

Tags: android, security, authentication, google-oauth

Recently I got an e-mail from Google where they complain about third party access:

*Your account is vulnerable to malicious activity because you’re allowing apps & devices that use less secure sign-in technology to access your account. You should turn off this type of access.*

This is from one of my apps in development. I use Google authentication as it is explained on developer page to get the user data to identify them in my system. Can anybody tell me why this is insecure?

This is the app code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);

    // Button click listeners
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    // [START configure_signin]
    // Configure sign-in to request offline access to the user's ID, basic
    // profile, and Google Drive. The first time you request a code you will
    // be able to exchange it for an access token and refresh token, which
    // you should store. In subsequent calls, the code will only result in
    // an access token. By asking for profile access (through
    // DEFAULT_SIGN_IN) you will also get an ID Token as a result of the
    // code exchange.
    String serverClientId = getString(R.string.web_client_id);
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestServerAuthCode(serverClientId)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    // [END configure_signin]

    // Build GoogleAPIClient with the Google Sign-In API and the above options.
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    //If there is the sign out intent, we sign the user out
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final boolean signOut = intent.getBooleanExtra(RequestCode.SIGNOUT_BUNDLE.name(), false);
    if (signOut)
    {
    //sign out
    }
}
```

..and this happens on server:

```
public OAuthBo processAuthentication(String authCode) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, ForbiddenException
{
    logger.info("processAuthentication()");

    try
    {
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), new FileReader(configuration.getClientSecretFile()));
        GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                      new NetHttpTransport(),
                      JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                      GOOGLEAPIS_OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL,
                      clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId(),
                      clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret(),
                      authCode,
                      "")  // Specify the same redirect URI that you use with your web
                                     // app. If you don't have a web version of your app, you can
                                     // specify an empty string.
                      .execute();

        // Get profile info from ID token
        GoogleIdToken idToken = tokenResponse.parseIdToken();

        idToken.verify(new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()).setAudience(Collections.singletonList(WEB_CLIENT_ID)).build());

        GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
        String email = payload.getEmail();

        //process user data

        //more code...
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.info("error while authentication. exception={}", e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new ForbiddenException(ErrorCodes.ERR_COULD_NOT_RETRIEVE_LOGIN_DATA);
    }
}
```

**[UPDATE]**
Additional information:
Google proposes to disable less secure apps (https://myaccount.google.com/security). If you do that, you can't even access your mails by Thunderbird any more. 
Here is an explanation why this could be:
https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/1201406

> Google/gmail calls apps that don't support OAuth2 "less secure". But,
>   that doesn't make them insecure. So what it means is gmail's meaning
>   of LessSecureApp is basically anything that doesn’t use OAuth2.

I figured out that on my development test account, less secure apps were always switched off by default (now I know why I was never able to connect to this account by Thunderbird). That also means that my apps also works with "insecure apps: off". But this doesn't solve my problem because I don't want to upset users when they get an email, that my app is "less secure".

If the comment from the link is correct, the question is: **How much OAuth2 is enough to satisfy Google?** I followed exactly this implementation from [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access), which is actually some kind of Google's OAuth2 implementation, except that I don't fetch an access token since I don't need it for getting the user's email address for identification and the REDIRECT_URL is an empty string, but this is valid according to the guide. Additionally, I added a verification check (updated in the code above as well):

```
    idToken.verify(new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()).setAudience(Collections.singletonList(WEB_CLIENT_ID)).build());
```

**[UPDATE 2]**
Maybe I'm interpreting the information from the mail wrong. Here is the content from the mail:

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Maybe they don't mean my Sign-In implementation. They could also mean my "service account access": I got the email on my main account. My main account is also my Google Play account and Google Pay account and so on. My app, especially my backend server, which uses a viewer account, has access to Google Play Development account, because it has to fetch information about subscriptions (via authorization): https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get.
But why do they inform me about such special configurations I've done on my own, you could never set by coincidence or whatever. Indeed this shit took me a lot of time to configure. And now they inform me about that? This is stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the Google Sign-In has nothing to do with the message. When I click on the exclamation mark, I see that this account has the following right:

*View and manage your Google Play Developer account*

Moreover my other Google Pay subscription test account does not give me such less-secure messages when I execute this check although this account downloaded the app via Google Play Alpha setup (to test in-app-billing). This confirms that I misunderstood this message).